# Calculate % position of the group in fabric js

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am stuck in a problem, don't know if this is related to the current thread.

I have created a rectangle inside the canvas like this:
[image]

The grey part is the canvas there is a small rectangle inside. This is the code I have written:

```
// THIS METHOD WHEN THE COMPONENT IS INITIALIZED
// THAT IS VERY FIRST TIME
// htmlCanvas = Canvas from HTML file
initCanvas(htmlCanvas) {
    this.mockupDrawableAreaCanvasSize = size;
    this.mainCanvasDivRef = htmlCanvas;
    fabric.textureSize = 4096;
    fabric.charWidthsCache = {};
    fabric.Object.prototype.borderScaleFactor = 2;
    fabric.Object.prototype.objectCaching = false;
    fabric.Object.prototype.noScaleCache = true;
    fabric.Object.prototype.lockScalingFlip = true;
    fabric.Object.prototype.hasRotatingPoint = true;
    fabric.Object.prototype.transparentCorners = false;
    fabric.Object.prototype.cornerColor = "rgb(255,255,255)";
    fabric.Object.prototype.cornerSize = 8;
    fabric.Object.prototype.cornerStrokeColor = "#48B774";
    fabric.Object.prototype.borderColor = "#48B774";
    fabric.Object.prototype.fill = "#FFFFFF";
    fabric.Object.prototype.cornerStyle = "rect";
    fabric.Object.prototype.borderOpacityWhenMoving = .5;
    fabric.Object.prototype.snapAngle = 90;
    fabric.Object.prototype.snapThreshold = 5;
    fabric.Object.prototype.charWidthsCache = {};

    this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas(htmlCanvas.nativeElement, this.defaultOption);

    this.canvas.backgroundColor = '#e8e8e8';
    this.canvas.uniScaleTransform = true;

    this.canvas.requestRenderAll()

    // -------
    const {
        width,
        height
    } = this.getDimensions();
    this.drawingBoard = new fabric.Rect({
        excludeFromExport: false,
        hasControls: false,
        height,
        selectable: false,
        borderColor: "transparent",
        strokeWidth: 0,
        stroke: 'transparent',
        fill: '#ffffff',
        width,
        preserveObjectStacking: false,
        absolutePositioned: true,
        clip_id: 'io_main_canvas',
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center',
        lockUniScaling: true,
    });
}
// Here mockupDrawableAreaCanvasSize = {width: 1080, height: 1080}
getDimensions() {
    let containerWidth: any = parseInt(this.mockupDrawableAreaCanvasSize.width, 10);
    let containerHeight: any = parseInt(this.mockupDrawableAreaCanvasSize.height, 10);
    const footer: any = document.querySelector('.footer-toolbar');
    const container = document.querySelector('.upper-canvas');
    const lowerCanvasEl = container && window.getComputedStyle(container, null);
    let canvasHeight = parseInt(lowerCanvasEl.height, 10) - 1.5 * parseInt(footer.offsetHeight, 10);
    const canvasWidth = parseInt(lowerCanvasEl.width, 10);

    // Complete fit
    if (containerWidth <= canvasWidth && containerHeight <= canvasHeight) {
        return {
            width: containerWidth,
            height: containerHeight
        }
    }
    if (canvasWidth < containerWidth) {
        containerWidth = canvasWidth - 80;
        canvasHeight = (containerWidth / (containerWidth / containerHeight)) - 6 * parseInt(footer.offsetHeight, 10)
    }
    let width = (containerWidth / containerHeight) * canvasHeight;

    return {
        width,
        height: canvasHeight
    }
}
```

This code works well in every use case. I want to position the objects at the same place where they were initially in the bigger or smaller screens.

My approach was:

*Group everything, Add the group to canvas, calculate the percentage, scale and finally ungroup*

But the objects are very small as shown in the below picture

[image]

How should I scale the object so that the whole content is a perfect fit in the group?

Group everything -> done

calculate % position of the group -> done

scale the group by ratio -> how?

-->>> The ratio between which values- group and canvas or group and drawing board?

apply for the same % position -->done

Ungroup --> done

Comment: Dinesh Rawat please provide codesandbox. It's hard to replicate your issue.

Comment: Adding to the comment from @Observer ... withe the code you provide there is no way to reproduce what you describe, you mention grouping and ungroup, but there is none of that in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found many issues with the approach I was trying to implement. Now instead od repositionin, grouping, etc.I am zooming the canvas